# Chart js disable popup

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to implement some text in middle of the Doughnut chart at Charts.js
The first step is 5to draw some text on the chart canvas.

[image]

When i move my cursor to red bar chartjs draw some tooltip(Red:300) on the canvas and deletes my text as a result.

[image]

How can i avoid all the canvas redraws by the chartjs after the initial chart is drawn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn off tooltips (and the associated redraw) by using the `showTooltips` option

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, {
    showTooltips: false
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For chart.js v2, the new way to do it is to pass an empty `events` array to the options.

your options:

```
let chartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    events: [],
    ...
};
```

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration